# Copy button for anchor link

Tags: links

I use my own webpage to help the users of my android app. I get many emails and many times they ask for help that is already in the help site. Sometimes the exact help they need is on a specific section of a page. So I would like to send them the link to that specific section. I have anchors for that. My problem is that I do not remember the names of all of the anchors. There are way too many. So, I am wondering if there is something similar like Google does to copy links for specific sections. For example take a look at this help site:

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code

In you scroll down a bit you will see the section "**Enable shrinking, obfuscation, and optimization**"
If you move the mouse over it, a link icon displays so you could tap on it and copy the link to that section.

So, is this possible with wordpress?

Comment: It is...  but you'd have to go and add links to each of the sections you wish to anchor to.  There's no way to just automate having the links appear, well there is, but depending on your DOM it could end up being super inefficient.  I've got JS that can be applied once the links are in place.  Do you have code examples of the content on your site?  (For reference, what I've done with this is FAQs... ...each Q has a link icon, you click on it and it copies a special URL, when that URL is used to visit the FAQ page it scrolls to that Q and opens it so the answer is visible.)